# Why Unity WaitForTargetFPS consuming too much time?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

I am new on unity profiler.I publish my game on iphone13 and debug it with unity profiler.

I set targetFrameRate 60, so one frame should cost 16.67ms.

However I find that PlayerLoop cost 33.48ms and WaitForTargetFPS cost 27.09ms.Subtraction equals 6.39ms, far less then 16.67ms. And I am really confused about this. Why WaitForTargetFPS cost so much and without WaitForTargetFPS this frame can finish in 16.67ms? The profiler screenshot is here.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppQeZ.png)

(I am not an English native speaker so if my expression is not clear please correct me. And Thanks)

Comment: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/124496/massive-cpu-usage-by-waitfortargetfps-in-the-profiler and [Unity API](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/profiler-markers.html#rendering)

Comment: "If the duration is larger than your application’s frame time should be (based on the targeted frame rate or vSync) your frames are taking too long to render or compute." If you can see the screenshot, the render thread are always waiting